# Create dynamic svg icons component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, jsx

I want to create a React component for my SVG icons but if I use this component several times (with different props) in another component, it always renders the same icon.

My `icon.js` component:

```
import { ReactComponent as ArrowDown} from '../assets/icons/icons-line-arrrow-down.svg';
import { ReactComponent as ArrowUp} from '../assets/icons/icons-line-arrrow-up.svg';

const iconTypes = {
  arrowDown: ArrowDown,
  arrowUp: ArrowUp,
}

const IconComponent = ({name, ...props}) => {
  let Icon = iconTypes[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;

};

export default IconComponent
```

The usage:

```
import Icon from 'components/Icon';
```

It works:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Icon name={"arrowDown"}/>
      </div>
    )}
}
```

It works too:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Icon name={"arrowUp"}/>
      </div>
    )}
}
```

It renders `ArrowDown` icon twice:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Icon name={"arrowDown"}/>
        <Icon name={"arrowUp"}/>
      </div>
    )}
}
```

So there is my question: why only the first SVG icon is rendered several times when I use my component twice and how to fix it?

Comment: Your code works fine...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works well, I've created the code snippet from it:

[CodeSandbox (JavaScript)](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-frog-xbnmw?fontsize=14)

[CodeSandbox (TypeScript)](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-blackwell-9kkgz1)

**`index.js`**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Icon from "./icon";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon name="arrowUp" />
      <Icon name="arrowDown" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**`icon.js`**

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowDown } from "./arrow-down.svg";
import { ReactComponent as ArrowUp } from "./arrow-up.svg";

const iconTypes = {
  arrowDown: ArrowDown,
  arrowUp: ArrowUp
};

const IconComponent = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  let Icon = iconTypes[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

export default IconComponent;
```

Comment: how do you assign `let Icon = iconTypes[name];` to typescript?

Comment: @RedBaron I added [the TypeScript snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-blackwell-9kkgz1).

Comment: thanks. my problem is though I want to do: `<Icon height={getIconSize(size)} fill={color} />` so I'm wondering where to define heigh and fill as props? also where did you import `ReactSVGComponent` from?

Comment: @RedBaron I think you could add them to `IconComponentProps` type.  `ReactSVGComponent` lies in `custom.d.ts`, this default `tsconfig.json` just auto-imports all your types. Check out [this updated snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-sid-8uzs94?file=/src/icon.tsx).